# Getting Waveforms with Negative Voltage Component on a Bridge Rectifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, bridge-rectifier

I am trying to simulate a Bridge Rectifier with 1N4005 diodes and an AC power source. The circuit looks like this: [link here](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/n9nfje447gr4/full-wave-rectifier/)

[image: Input and output waveforms]

I am getting a waveform that drops below zero V, is this behavior acceptable for a circuit like this? Thank you.

Comment: In your test circuit, load resistor of 50 ohms might give you a short negative glitch. When load resistor is very much larger, like a X1 oscilloscope probe at one megohm, you can have a different problem...waveform doesn't go quite to zero. The 'scope + cable capacitance is enough to remain charged by a little bit to a +ve voltage.

Answer (score 4):

> *I am getting a waveform that drops below zero V, is this behavior
>   acceptable for a circuit like this?*

Yes it's perfectly normal for low speed diodes like the 1N400x series. They have a reverse recovery time of many microseconds and this means that they will continue to conduct for "several microseconds" when the voltage is reversed. This one (from General Semiconductor) is about as bad as it gets: -

[image]

It looks like you are using an applied AC frequency that is "beyond the scope" for this type of diode. Look for fast-recovery diodes if this is a problem. Also try using a smaller maximum time-step in your simulator - it will give a much more precise resolution at the expense of a longer calculation time.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I'll be sure that my diodes take note!

Comment: @[Bactrian](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/82/2011_Trampeltier_1528.JPG)Fan I'm glad you didn't [get the hump](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-the-hump) about this.

Comment: I apologize for not acknowledging your excellent pun. It has brought me great joy